# JQuery $('<div></div>') doesn't create proper div element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").bind("click", function() {
        var div = $('<div></div>');
        $(".label").append(div);
        div.html($(".textField").val());
        console.log(div);
    });
});
```

with html:

```
<input type="text" class="textField"/>
<input type="button" class="button" value=" &gt;&gt;"/>
<div class="label" style="color: red;"></div>
```

and when I click the button, nothing happens. Console output shows that created `div` is not a proper div object.
But when I copy onclick function handler code into browser console and run it, it works properly. 
 Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashishbpatil1/tLbv5m3q/). 
What is wrong here?

Comment: Use `on()` to bind events, `bind()` is deprecated.

Comment: code is working at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1padvxvc/

Comment: `div` will not be a proper `DOM` element. It is instead a jQuery-ified element. Essentially a jQiery wrapper to the underlying `DOM` element. `div[0]` should give you access to the raw `DOM` element.

Answer (score 2):

**Change your Code**
JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".button").on("click", function() {
                var div = "<div class='id-of-div'></div>"; //changes
                $(".label").append(div);
                div.html($(".textField").val());
                console.log(div);
            });
        });
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="textField"/>
    <input type="button" class="button" value=" &gt;&gt;"/>
<div class="label" style="color: red;"></div>
```

I Think, This is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`.click()` event](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".button").click(function () {
      var div = $('<div></div>');
      $(".label").append(div);
      div.html($(".textField").val());
      console.log((div));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have something wrong in your code dependencies or structure because this seems to be working. Here's your code running on codepen: http://codepen.io/chriteixeira/pen/qNvoPN

About the log object not being a proper html, maybe you're comparing the plain output in the browser console instead of the log console. To make sure you're comparing the same data, you should run this:

```
var $div = $('<div></div>');
console.log($div);
```

Running like this, the result should be the same as in the codepen example.

Comment: Yep, in a hurry I started to write javascript right in the head section and my $("<div></div>") was converted to $(""). Now I moved javascript code to the separate .js file and it works. Voted to close this question.